# Sync framework: How to use/sync single data (file) across multiple instances of same application

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework, collaboration, collaborative, operational-transform, collaborative-editing

Currently we have an application (a diagram editor), that have the ability to save and load (serialize) its state in a xml file.

Now we want this application to behave like Microsoft OneNote application. Where multiple users have the ability to access the same file.

Later we may also need to enhance with other things like, (1)what is changed and who changed it, (2)option to resolve conflicts if any.

I came to know about sync framework to resolve this. so far, i have not tried it.

All i want is,

1. Virtually single file should be edited by multiple instances of
   same application.
2. We need a dll (sync framework) that does following

   - It takes complete responsibility of file handling.
   - Using this dll, each instance of the application will notify their own changes.
   - Each instance of the application should have the ability to detect the changes that is recently made (when, who, what are the changes).

My question:

1. Will sync framework be suitable for this requirement?
2. If so, is there a demo application that represents this?

Comment: Found some related content:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_transformation
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collaborative_real-time_editor

http://swarmjs.github.io/about/
http://etherpad.org/
https://togetherjs.com/
http://sharejs.org/
https://github.com/opencoweb/coweb/wiki

All these seems to be related to web platform.
Trying to find a solution that also considers all platform (desktop and web app) though offline file access.

Answer (score 0):

No, Sync Fx cannot handle this. There's a file sync provider, but that's not smart enough to determine what has changed in terms of the actual contents of the file.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.
If i want to make a onenote like app. Will Sync Fx be useful in any case? 

 1. If so, can you give me brief idea on what problem will it solve?
 2. if not, is there any other framework that helps to solve my problem?